# How can I delete tempory files when I record a video in Swift with AVFoundation?

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I had this in objective c, but I don't know how to convert this to Swift. When I tried this traduction, I obtain a crash in library.removeItemAtPath.. I don't know what is: ^{ ... There are other form to save and then remove this for not obtain conflicts??

```
   dispatch_async(_captureQueue, ^{
            [_encoder finishWithCompletionHandler:^{
                self.isCapturing = NO;
                _encoder = nil;
                ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
                [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:url completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
                    NSLog(@"save completed");
                    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:nil];
                }];
            }];
        });
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will want to delete your temp file at the beginning and end of each recording just in case the user during recording exits the app or it crashes
leaving behind a video chunk that will upset the writer on next write session

A complete example of a video writer in swift can be had here:

https://github.com/OhioVR/CineVid/blob/master/CineVid/ViewController.swift

although it doesn't do its stated task at 4/30/2015 it can be easily modified to remove the attempted iso flipping effect and you can use it to save videos of any frame rate and resolution supported by the device. And you get a full image processing pipeline to go with it.

Here are the relevant parts in swift for your case:

```
func startRecording () {

     ///stuff you'd do to start the recording including deleting
     ///your temp file if it exists from the last recording session
     ////SET OUTPUT URL AND PATH. DELETE ANY FILE THAT EXISTS THERE
     var tmpdir = NSTemporaryDirectory()
     outputPath = "\(tmpdir)output.mov"
     outputURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:outputPath as String)!
     let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
     if filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(outputPath) {
        filemgr.removeItemAtPath(outputPath, error: nil)
     }

}


func stopRecording() {

    ////FINISH WRITING AND TRANSFER RESULTS TO THE CAMERA ROLL
    assetWriterVideoInput.markAsFinished()
    assetWriterAudioInput.markAsFinished()
    self.videoWriter.finishWritingWithCompletionHandler({ () -> Void in
        if self.videoWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatus.Failed {
            println("VIDEO WRITER ERROR: \(self.videoWriter.error.description)")
        } else {
            let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
            if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(self.outputPath as String) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
                    if UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(self.outputPath) {  ///(fileURL) {
                        var complete : ALAssetsLibraryWriteVideoCompletionBlock = {reason in println("reason \(reason)")}
                        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.outputPath as String, self, "savingCallBack:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
                    } else {
                        println("the file must be bad!")
                    }
                });
            } else {
                println("there is no file")
            }
        }
    });


}

func savingCallBack(video: NSString, didFinishSavingWithError error:NSError, contextInfo:UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>){
    println("the file has been saved sucessfully to the camera roll")
    //you could delete the temp file here if you like

}
```